# pandas/python : Convert a list with punctutations in to str form in a column of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe  that looks like this:

| Name |
| --- |
| ['-','"','blah','+',',' ] |
| ['.','!'] |

I want the output to be like:

| Name |
| --- |
| -,",blah,+,, |
| .! |

I have commas in the list as well.

Can someone suggest how to do this in python

Comment: I cannot. At least with what you showed. You only showed text representations while I need the actual types. What gives `type(df['Name'].iloc[0])` (assuming you dataframe is `df`)